# The results of python and c++ are different for nested for statements

Tags: python, c++

I am writing algorithms in c ++ and python.

The algorithm is to output `when n = 7, (0,1,2,3), (0,1,2,4) ... (3,4,5,6)` I implemented this through a nested for statement, but the values ​​of c ++ and python are different.

Can you tell me why?

And, for example, when i use for i in range, do i always start at 0? If there is a way to set the initial value of `range()`, let me know.

**C++**

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for(int j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
            for(int k = j+1; k < n; ++k)
                for(int l = k+1; l < n; ++l)
                    cout << i << " " << j << " " << k << " " << l << endl;
```

**Python**

```
for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            for k in range(i+2, n):
                for l in range(i+3, n):
                    print(i, j, k, l)
```

Comment: Your `k` starts at `j+1` in the C++ code, and `i+2` in the Python code. Your `l` start value is also inconsistent. The code is clearly not equivalent.

Comment: the loops are not remotely the same?  inner loop starts at k+1 in c++ and i+3 in python?

Comment: The reason is that, for example, range (j=i+1,n) does not work, so it is used forcibly T_T ..

Comment: `for k in range(j+1, n)` – `j` *is* already defined here...

Comment: Oh, my God! I did not think Python was unfamiliar with it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different indexes in the loops:

```
for(int k = j+1; k < n; ++k)
for(int l = k+1; l < n; ++l)
```

and

```
 for k in range(i+2, n):
 for l in range(i+3, n):
```

Basically, the indexes in the inner loops in your C++ code change accordingly to the loop that is one line above them. In your python code, all the indexes change only when the first loop changes.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of @khelwood:

Your `k` starts at `j+1` in the C++ code, and `i+2` in the Python code. Your `l` start value is also inconsistent. The code is not equivalent.

Also, you can add initial value as the first argument in `range()`